# Where to Find Free Music with Creative Commons License

Tags: free, creative-commons, database

Is there any website that provides lots of music files with Creative Commons license?

I have a personal blog and use photos with CC license from Flickr. I also want to produce small video presentations with background music. I want to use light listening music like Kitaro, Yiruma etc. Is there any website that provides this kind of music freely?

Answer (score 3):

Try [Jamendo](http://www.jamendo.com/en/).

I have no experience with the site, but a brother of a friend is an indie film-maker and uses music from there all the time. (And he *never* returns my calls.) Ha.

Comment: Thank you, it is a great site. No wonder that your brother doesn't return your calls :)

Answer (score 1):

Also check out the venerable [archive.org.](http://www.archive.org/index.php) There's an amazing amount of Creative Commons media in every conceivable form including music. Downside is that it's kinda slow and not intuitive as far as searching goes.

Comment: Thank you vey much for the suggestion. This is very useful too. But as you said navigation is a bit difficult. 

Answer (score 1):

Soundcloud has tons as well: http://soundcloud.com/creativecommons

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys,

just wanted to introduce my free creative commons music website:
[www.bensound.com](http://www.bensound.com)

Ben